# D3 toggle between straight edges and multiple curved edges

Tags: d3.js, graph, force-layout

I have a D3 force graph similar to the one in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292), except there can be a lot more than 2 edges between a pair of nodes nodes. I would like the ability to switch between visualizing all of the edges, and just a single, straight edge. I have gotten this to work by simply changing edges' visibility (hidden or visible), however there are so many edges between nodes that there is visible lag.

My idea to fix this is to only run the force simulation on the straight edges, instead of also including all of the curved edges. This would limit the edges to one edge per pair of nodes, thus making the force simulation algorithm less intensive.

Is it possible to do this while still being able to render the curved edges that aren't being used in the force algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the biggest computing boggleneck actually came in the `.on("tick", tickActions)` step when the code is computing how to draw all the paths, even the ones that aren't visible.

For anyone that's interested, I changed the `tick actions` function to first check a `type` variable before drawing the edge or not:

```
function tickActions() {
    // plot the curved links
    link.attr("d", function(d) {
        if (d.type != draw_type) return null;

        // code to draw paths

    });
}
```

By changing the `draw_type` variable, you can decide which edges actually get computed and drawn.

In addition to this, you will also need to ignore the strength of certain edges. I knew that I wanted my graph to be spaced based only on the straight edges, so I did the following for the `simulation.force('link', link_force)` attribute:

```
var link_force = d3.forceLink()

    // code for .id and .distance attributes

    // return 0 for all non
    .strength(function(d) {
        if (d.type != 'straight') return 0;
        return 0.3;
    });
```

By setting the strength of all non-straight edges to 0, the force algorithm basically ignores them when spacing nodes.

Finally, I added a `restart_network()` function which updates the graph. It's possible to use this function to change the actual link data seen by the graph, but I decided to include the other changes as well.

```
function restart_network() {
    simulation.force("link", link_force);
    simulation.alpha(1).restart();
}
```